# A movie about a boy growing up in a TV studio

Tags: identify-this-movie

I am looking for a movie about a boy/child that grows up thinking he is in the real world, but actually he is living between walls of a tv-studio.
The world saw him grow up and stuff. I think later on he finds out that this is not the real world. I think this happened when he was sailing on his boat and bumped against a wall.

What movie is it?

Answer (score 25):

You're thinking of *[The Truman Show](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120382/)* (1998), starring Jim Carrey.  He actually learns that he is the subject of a television program earlier; he uses the sailboat to reach the
dome surrounding his "world" at the end of the film.

Comment: Not sure he could be described as a "boy", as he's pretty much a full-grown adult for 99% of the movie (basically everything except the opening setup scenes).